# iOS native user interface and Qt core code

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, interface-builder, qtcore

I want to use a native iOS user interface using xCode interface builder together with Qt (non-user interface) code. As far as I can see there are two options:

1. Create a standard iOS Qt app and put an UIView and other elements on top of the basic Qt user interface.
2. Create a plain iOS app in xCode and add the Qt code to it.

Option 2.) is probably tricky due to all the Qt compiler stuff so I will skip this.

Option 1.): Putting the iOS user interface on top of the existing Qt user interface structure does not seem very efficient. What is the best way to add a native iOS Ui on top of the Qt app? Is there a way to change the Qt app so that it does not create it's own user interface?

Regards,

Comment: Do you want to use objective c or Swift for the UI code?

Comment: Both, Swift and objective-c, are fine.